# Ecllipse "Debug Current Instruction Pointer" Slow

Tags: java, eclipse, centos

For some reason when I am debugging Java code with Eclipse on CentOS my debug current instruction pointer takes up to 5 minutes to update its location after a breakpoint is hit. The code itself will be stopped at the breakpoint but the visual part of the pointer does not show up. Any tips to fix this?

Comment: Do you use an Eclipse version older than 2018-09 (4.9)? I'm asking because of this: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.9/jdt.php#step-result-timeout

Comment: It is from 2018-12 (4.10.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinstall eclipse to fix this issue. (Installed same version and it worked fine)